# iff criterion for n-dimensional vector bundle being trivial

Tags: vector-bundles

Prove that an $n$ dimensional vector bundle $p: E \to B$ is trivial iff there exists a continuous map $\pi: E \to \mathbb{R}^n$ whose restriction to each fiber $p^{-1}(b), b \in B,$ is a vector space isomorphism.

This is for my high school math independent study and my teacher is unable to help.

Comment: Use the hypothesis to construct an isomorphism between $E$ and $B \times \mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: Can you prove one direction of the equivalence?

Comment: "...and my teacher is unable to help": but who suggested this independent study ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Defn:** Two bundles $p_1:E_1\to B$ and $p_2:E_2\to B$ are isomorphic iff we have some map $f:E_1\to E_2$ such that $p_1=p_2\circ f$ and for each $b\in B$, the map $f|_{p_1^{-1}(b)}:p_1^{-1}(b)\to p_2^{-1}(b)$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

If the bundle is trivial, by definition we have some isomorphism $f:E\to B\times \mathbb R^n$ such that $f|_{p^{-1}(b)}:p^{-1}(b)\to \mathbb R^n$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces, as desired.

If we have such a $\pi$, define $f:E\to B\times \mathbb R^n$ by $f(x)=(p(x),\pi(x))$. This is an isomorphism since if $p_0:B\times \mathbb R^n\to B$ is the standard projection, we have $p = p_0\circ f$ and for each $b\in B$, $f|_{p^{-1}(b)}=\pi(x)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Alex's solution preceded mine: +1

Answer (score 2):

Morphisms $\pi:E\to \mathbb R^n$ of the type you describe  and trivializations $j:E\stackrel {\cong}{\to }  B\times \mathbb R^n$ of $E$ correspond to each other under the bijective correspondence $$   \pi :E\to \mathbb R^n\iff    j:E\stackrel {\cong}{\to }  B\times \mathbb R^n:e\mapsto (p(e),\pi(e))          $$

**Edit**
The map $\pi$ is interesting because it is a particular case of a *Gauss map*, a map $E\to \mathbb R^N$ supposed  only to be a linear *monomorphism* on the fibres of $E$.
These Gauss maps permit one to classify vector bundles on a paracompact space $B$ by homotopy classes of continuous maps from $B$ into an infinite Grassmannian.
This is explained in Chapter 3 of Husemoller's [Fibre Bundles](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Fibre_Bundles.html?id=DPr_BSH89cAC&redir_esc=y).